# Tender Offer from Canadian Company as a US investor

Tags: canada, roth-ira, canada-revenue-agency, tender-offer

I am US investor that holds shares in a Canadian company inside of my ROTH IRA. This Canadian company has recently announced a tender offer at a higher price then the current market price so I am thinking I would like to participate. The issue I am running into is that it seems that the Canadian government will withhold 15% of the payout as a 'dividend'. Some articles online are saying that I will be fine since it is a tax-advantaged account and they won't withhold and others are saying that even though they aren't supposed to, they will. Any insight would be appreciated
https://www.suredividend.com/canadian-taxes-us-investors/#dividendtaximplications

Comment: It's tax-advantaged in the US, I don't know if Canada would care. You can file a claim for refund or claim treaty benefit if there's a relevant one.